# Retrieve a single row from Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

If I need to retrieve a single row of data from the database, why can't I do this when I want to insert that id into another table:

```
'user_id' => $query->row()->id
```

Is there any way to do this without a foreach loop if all I want is a single piece of data?

The full code is:

```
$this->db->where('username', $this->input->post('username'));
        $query = $this->db->get('members');

        $data = array(
            'first' => $this->input->post('first'),
            'last' => $this->input->post('last'),
            'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
            'phone' => $this->input->post('phone'),
            'address' => $this->input->post('address'),
            'city' => $this->input->post('city'),
            'state' => $this->input->post('state'),
            'zip' => $this->input->post('zip'),
            'comments' => $this->input->post('comments'),
            'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
            'user_id' => $query->row()->id
        );

        $this->db->insert('contact', $data);
```

Comment: No, I get an error that I'm trying to get a property of a non-object.

Comment: Are you sure that the row you want exists in the 'members' table?

Comment: OK, I figured out why I got the error, the ID wasn't in the DB.  But the larger question remains, is the correct syntax "$query->row()->id"?

Comment: Yes you can use method chaining for this operation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$query->row()->id` is correct, yes.  Given that the field is called 'id' in your table, and the row exists that you want.  You can check `$query->num_rows()` to see how many rows were returned.

Answer (score 0):

```
$the_data= $query->row();

$user_id= $the_data->id;
```

<strike>don't think you can do method chaining like in your example.</strike>

Comment: Yes, you can use the chaining.